# Nested loop in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, html-lists, thymeleaf

I'm a newbie to Thymeleaf.

I have two objects- `Classroom` & `Student`: each Classroom contains a `List<Student>` and I can have a list of classrooms: `List<Classroom>`.

What I want to be able to do with Thymeleaf is the equivalent of the below java code:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < classroomList.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(classroomList.get(i).getRoomName());
                for(int x = 0; x < studentList.size(); x++){
                    System.out.println(studentList.get(x));
                }
            }
```

So the output would be: `{classroom1{joe1,joe2}, classroom2{joe3}}...`

But I need to be able to do this in HTML with Thymeleaf (by passing a list of classrooms) so I can make it look nice.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As a note, this is poor practice in Java both because it's overly complicated and because `get()` can be O(n). In both Java and Thymeleaf you want an iterator; in the latter case, you're looking for `th:each`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `th:each`:

```
<div th:each="classroom : ${classroomList}">
    <div th:text="${classroom.name}"></div> 
    <ul>
      <div th:each="student : ${classroom.studentList}">
         <li>"${student.name}"</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: <div>"${classroom.name}"</div>. should be <div th:text="${classroom.name}"></div>

Comment: @Arun you are right. I improved the answer!